# Java: Shift/Rotate Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reference, rotation

My question should actually be really simple:
I have an object array of Players.(players[])
I want to have a function that rotates this array until an index:

```
public void rotateArray(Object[] array, int index)
```

This would convert

```
{Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5}
```

with an index of 2 to:

```
{Player3, Player4, Player5, Player1, Player2}
```

But I want to prevent issues with references.
I've tried System.arraycopy() but either I was to dumb to get it working or I is the wrong method for this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the rotated array?

Comment: I want to use this function to set a order to call these objects.

Comment: Can't you rather iterate in that order? Array copy will be an expensive operation everytime you do it.

Comment: What do you mean by iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be necessary to make a copy of the array to use arraycopy, which I recommend as it should be the fastest.  The only reason to avoid a copy is if the array is very large and memory is tight.

```
public void rotateArray(Object[] array, int index)
{
    Object[] result;

    result = new Object[array.length];

    System.arraycopy(array, index, result, 0, array.length - index);
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, array.length - index, index);

    System.arraycopy(result, 0, array, 0, array.length);
}
```

Comment: I'll check this to make sure there are no off-by-one or indexing mistakes.

Comment: N.B. to anyone who is trying to use this for generalized rotation (negatives or rotations larger than the length of the array): this code will crash. Insert at the beginning:
`index %= array.length;
if (index > 0) {
  index += array.length;
}`
Note that the negative check is necessary, because Java's mod is not a real math mod: it can produce negatives.

Comment: I never heard of System.arrayCopy before... I'm going to be using this a in the future.

Answer (score 17):

This one-line solution rotates the array in-place, with constant extra memory and linear time:

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), -index);
```

Comment: I upvote this. How is possible that this is not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient solution for big arrays, uses O(1) space:

```
 public static void rotateArray(int[] a, int i) {
    i %= a.length;
    reverse(a, 0, a.length);
    reverse(a, 0, i);
    reverse(a, i, a.length);
 }

 public static void reverse(int[] a, int l, int r) {
    for (int left = l, right = r - 1; left < right; left++, right--) {
        int temp = a[left];
        a[left]  = a[right];
        a[right] = temp;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this algorithm is correct in all cases. Consider the sequence BCDA, where the objective is to rotate until A is first. At each reversal step, this algorithm produces : BCDA->ADCB->CDAB (Incorrect).

Comment: I've checked and the code works correctly. Rotation happens cyclically to the right. e.g. a= {1,2,3,4} i = 0 --> nothing is rotated. i = 1 --> a = {4,1,2,3} etc. i = 4 --> will put the array to initial state(i=a.length). i = 5 is the same as i = 1, i = 6 same as i = 2 etc.

Comment: My bad - I was interpreting "i" as the index of the element which should be first after the rotation is complete, rather than the number of rotations to perform (hence setting i = a.length-1; )

Comment: No problem. Yes, i is not an index but a shift on one position of all all elements to the right